# Return Date of onEdit in specific column

Tags: google-sheets

I am new to google sheets and was trying to create a script that will put a date of edit of certain cell.
That went fine but then I had a problem where it will not work when I paste more than one cell.
So I found a solution, but now it checks all the cells in the spreadsheet and gives a date to every cell I edited.
My goal to would be if anything in column B will be eddited, then in column A it will return a date of edit. But with a fact that I can sometimes paste 10 positions and it will still return dates to all of them.

```
function onEdit(e) {

  if(
    e.range.columnStart !=2 && e.range.rowStart > 2 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() != "Arkusz2" && e.range.offset(0,0).getValue()!=""
  ){return}
  var currentDate = new Date();
  e.range.offset(0,-1).setValue(currentDate);
  
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `But with a fact that I can sometimes paste 10 positions and it will still return dates to all of them.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. It has already been answerd, so thank you for good will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Suggestion

You can use `getColumn()` instead in order to apply the `onEdit` function to a specific column.

Let me know if this code works for you:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 2 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Arkusz2" && e.range.offset(0,0).getValue()!="") {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    e.range.offset(0, -1).setValue(currentDate);
  } else return;
}
```

### Reference:

[getColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/developer-metadata-location#getcolumn)

Comment: Thank you, this is excatly what I was looking for. Now it works perfectly.